Why AnimatedVisibility doesn't work when I use Shared Element Transition?
So I want to do some animations, most of the elements are animated by AnimatedVisibility composable, but for two texts I need to use Shared element transition as well.
When I use Shared element transition, the AnimatedVisibility composable seems not working, the elements just pop in and pop out without animation. If I remove the Shared element transition part of the code the AnimatedVisibility works as expected again.
I created a simple code, where you can see how my layouts look like. Actually it doesn't contain all of the elements, just the minimal.
@OptIn(ExperimentalSharedTransitionApi::class)
@Composable
fun MainScreen(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    var isExpanded by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    val totalDuration = 2000
    val height by animateDpAsState(
        targetValue = if (isExpanded) 200.dp else 400.dp,
        animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = totalDuration)
    )

    Column(
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))

        SharedTransitionLayout {
            AnimatedContent(targetState = isExpanded) { targetState ->
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(8.dp)
                        .height(height)
                        .background(Color.LightGray)
                ) {
                    Layout1(
                        onButtonClick = {
                            isExpanded = !isExpanded
                        },
                        isExpanded = targetState,
                        animatedVisibilityScope = this@AnimatedContent
                    )

                    Layout2(
                        onButtonClick = {
                            isExpanded = !isExpanded
                        },
                        isExpanded = targetState,
                        animatedVisibilityScope = this@AnimatedContent
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalSharedTransitionApi::class)
@Composable
fun SharedTransitionScope.Layout1(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onButtonClick: () -> Unit,
    isExpanded: Boolean,
    animatedVisibilityScope: AnimatedVisibilityScope
) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            if (isExpanded) {
                Text(
                    color = Color.Black,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .sharedBounds(
                            rememberSharedContentState(key = "text"),
                            animatedVisibilityScope = animatedVisibilityScope,
                            enter = fadeIn(
                                animationSpec = tween(2000)
                            ),
                            exit = fadeOut(
                                animationSpec = tween(2000)
                            )
                        ),
                    fontSize = 18.sp,
                    text = "Animated"
                )
            }
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))

        AnimatedVisibility(
            visible = !isExpanded,
            enter = fadeIn(
                animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 1200)
            ),
            exit = fadeOut(
                animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 800)
            )
        ) {
            Button(onClick = onButtonClick) {
                Text(
                    color = Color.Black,
                    text = "Button 1"
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalSharedTransitionApi::class)
@Composable
fun SharedTransitionScope.Layout2(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onButtonClick: () -> Unit,
    isExpanded: Boolean,
    animatedVisibilityScope: AnimatedVisibilityScope
) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))

        if (!isExpanded) {
            Text(
                color = Color.Black,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .sharedBounds(
                        rememberSharedContentState(key = "text"),
                        animatedVisibilityScope = animatedVisibilityScope,
                        enter = fadeIn(
                            animationSpec = tween(2000)
                        ),
                        exit = fadeOut(
                            animationSpec = tween(2000)
                        )
                    ),
                fontSize = 55.sp,
                text = "Animated"
            )
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))

        AnimatedVisibility(
            visible = isExpanded,
            enter = fadeIn(
                animationSpec = keyframes {
                    durationMillis = 2000
                    0.0f at 0
                    0.8f at 0
                    1f at 1
                }
            ),
            exit = fadeOut(
                animationSpec = tween(800)
            )
        ) {
            Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                Button(onClick = onButtonClick) {
                    Text(
                        color = Color.Black,
                        text = "Button 2 with more text"
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

The reason why I want to use shared element transition, because I have two texts one time just one of them will be visible, but when I change the state (isExpanded), one text must animate into the other, so the fontSize and position as well. Since I have to use two different composable for each version, I couldn't write the animation from scratch.
If I missed something please let me know, but if you have idea how I should do the animation without shared element transition it is also good for me.
